# custom higher order function invocation gives Non type-variable argument in the constraint error

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I am new to Haskell, I was trying to figure out higher order function fundament. So I created this example

```
times3 x = x * 3
fn f x = f (x+3)
transform x = x+5
mapThenComputeV1 f f1 x = f (f1 (transform (x)))
```

upon calling

```
mapThenComputeV1 fn times3 4
```

I am getting this exception

```
*Main> mapThenComputeV1 fn times3 4

<interactive>:2:1: error:
    * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (t1 -> t2)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall t1 t2. (Num t1, Num (t1 -> t2)) => t1 -> t2
```

I am completely clueless, please help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argument `f` in `mapThenComputeV1` is a function that you are going to apply. You are passing `fn` that accepts two arguments, but you have extra parenthesis in `mapThenComputeV1` body.
Try this:

```
mapThenComputeV1 f f1 x = f f1 (transform (x))
output> 36
```

But I'm not sure if it is what you expect to achieve.

Comment: I got it, however from error message I could not figure out the actual problem. I still don't understand what the error message says, is there any way to get a readable stack trace to understand this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your `mapThenComputeV1` have type `(a -> b) -> (Int -> a) -> Int -> b` (Or something similar).

You try to apply it to `fn times3 4`.

```
fn :: (Int -> a) -> Int -> a
```

so haskell try to apply `mapThenComputeV1` to `fn`, but see that types doesn't matches. `Int` no way can be inferred to `(Int -> a)`.

**PS**: Try to add explicit types to your definitions. It usually help me to find a problem.

**PPS**: If you explain what you want to achieve with `mapThenComputeV1` we can help you to fix your example.